# if else statment to display icons in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I need to display icons according to `data.id` value, (the example icons display is in the comment code as well. can you suggest to me how to give an **else if**  condition to display this icon according to the `data.id` value?

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-pascal-case */
import React, { Fragment, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "antd";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Menu, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import * as Icons from "../../assets/svg/mobile-icons";
import * as Icons2 from "../../assets/svg/icon";

import catData from  './CategoriesData'

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

const catWomen = catData.catWomen.map ((data) => {


  function loadIcon() {
  if (data.id === '1') {

    return <Icons2.frock01 />

  }  else if (data.id === '2') {

    return <Icons2.frock02 />

  } else if (data.id === '3'){ 

    return <Icons2.frock03 />

  } else if (data.id === '4'){ 

    return <Icons2.frock04 />

  } else if (data.id === '5'){ 

    return <Icons2.frock05 />

  } else  { 

    return <Icons2.frock06 />
  }
}

  return(
    { 
      id: data.id, 
      name: data.name, 
      icon: loadIcon,
      childs: data.childs
    }
  )
  }
)

const catMen = catData.catMen.map ((data) => {
  return(
    { 
      id: data.id, 
      name: data.name, 
      icon: <Icons2.frock01 />,
      childs: data.childs
    }
  )
  }
)

const catKids = catData.catKid.map ((data) => {
  return(
    { 
      id: data.id, 
      name: data.name, 
      icon: <Icons2.frock01 />,  
      childs: data.childs
    }
  )
  }
)

/*
const catWomen = [
  { id: 1, name: "See All", icon: <Icons2.seeall />, childs: [] },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Clothes",
    icon: <Icons2.frock01 />,
    childs: ["item2", "item8"],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Shoes",
    icon: <Icons2.shoes06 />,
    childs: ["item3", "item7"],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Bags", icon: <Icons2.purse01 />, childs: ["item4", "item6"] },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Accessories",
    icon: <Icons2.bag05 />,
    childs: ["item5", "item2"],
  },
  { id: 6, name: "Beauty", icon: <Icons2.hat02 />, childs: ["item6", "item4"] },
];

const catMen = [
  { id: 1, name: "See All", icon: <Icons2.seeall />, childs: [] },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Clothes",
    icon: <Icons2.shirt1 />,
    childs: ["item2", "item8"],
  },
  { id: 3, name: "Shoes", icon: <Icons2.shoes1 />, childs: ["item3", "item7"] },
  { id: 4, name: "Bags", icon: <Icons2.bag05 />, childs: ["item4", "item6"] },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Accessories",
    icon: <Icons2.purse02 />,
    childs: ["item5", "item2"],
  },
  { id: 6, name: "Grooming", icon: <Icons2.hat />, childs: ["item6", "item4"] },
];

const catKids = [
  { id: 1, name: "See All", icon: <Icons2.seeall />, childs: [] },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Clothes",
    icon: <Icons2.shirt1 />,
    childs: ["item2", "item8"],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Shoes",
    icon: <Icons2.shoes05 />,
    childs: ["item3", "item7"],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Bags", icon: <Icons2.bag05 />, childs: ["item4", "item6"] },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Accessories",
    icon: <Icons2.bow />,
    childs: ["item5", "item2"],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Grooming",
    icon: <Icons2.hat03 />,
    childs: ["item6", "item4"],
  },
];
*/
const Categories = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function SubCategories(props) {
    return (
      <Transition
        enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
        enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
        enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
        leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
        leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
        leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
      >
        <Menu.Items className="origin-top absolute w-auto rounded-md shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 divide-y divide-gray-100 focus:outline-none">
          <div className="py-1 flex">{props.children}</div>
        </Menu.Items>
      </Transition>
    );
  }

  function DropDownItem(props) {
    const items = props.data.map((item) => (
      <Menu.Item key={item.id.toString()}>
        {({ active }) => (
          <div
            onMouseOver={() => setChild(item.id)}
            onClick={() => {
              item.id === 1
                ? navigate(`/allproducts?mainProductCategory=${props.parent}`)
                : navigate(
                    `/allproducts?mainProductCategory=${props.parent}&category=${item.name}`
                  );
            }}
            className={classNames(
              active ? "bg-gray-100 text-gray-900" : "text-gray-700",
              "grid grid-cols-8 block px-4 py-2 text-xs"
            )}
          >
            <div className="col-span-7">{item.name}</div>
            <div className="col-span-1">{item.icon}</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Menu.Item>
    ));
    return (
      <>
        <div className="border-r border-gray-300 w-40 text-sm">{items}</div>
      </>
    );
  }

  const [child, setChild] = useState(1);

  function LoadChilds(props) {
    const childs = props.data[props.child - 1];
    const subItems = childs.childs.map((item) => (
      <Menu.Item key={item.toString()}>
        {({ active }) => (
          <div
            onClick={() => navigate(`/allproducts?mainProductCategory=${props.parent}&category=${childs.name}&subCategory=${item}`)}
            className={classNames(
              active ? "bg-gray-100 text-gray-900" : "text-gray-700",
              "block px-4 py-2 text-sm"
            )}
          >
            {item}
          </div>
        )}
      </Menu.Item>
    ));
    return <div className="w-56">{subItems}</div>;
  }

  const dropdownRef = useRef();

  return (
    <Row className="bg-white w-full" style={{ position: "fixed", border: 0 }}>
      <Col offset={2}>
        <div className="flex w-full gap-6 text-xs cursor-pointer mt-0.5">
          <Menu as="div">
            <div
              className={`border-b-2 border-b-white hover:border-b-red-400 p-2`}
              onClick={() => navigate(`/allproducts`)}
            >
              <p>Shop</p>
            </div>
          </Menu>

          <Menu as="div">
            <Menu.Button
              className={`border-b-2 border-b-white hover:border-b-red-400 p-2`}
            >
              <p>Women</p>
            </Menu.Button>
            <div ref={dropdownRef}>
              <SubCategories>
                <DropDownItem data={catWomen} parent="Women" />
                <LoadChilds child={child} data={catWomen} parent="Women" />
              </SubCategories>
            </div>
          </Menu>

          <Menu as="div">
            <Menu.Button
              className={`border-b-2 border-b-white hover:border-b-red-400 p-2`}
            >
              <p>Men</p>
            </Menu.Button>
            <div ref={dropdownRef}>
              <SubCategories>
                <DropDownItem data={catMen} parent="Men" />
                <LoadChilds child={child} data={catMen} parent="Men" />
              </SubCategories>
            </div>
          </Menu>

          <Menu as="div">
            <Menu.Button
              className={`border-b-2 border-b-white hover:border-b-red-400 p-2`}
            >
              <p>Kids</p>
            </Menu.Button>
            <div ref={dropdownRef}>
              <SubCategories>
                <DropDownItem data={catKids} parent="Kids" />
                <LoadChilds child={child} data={catKids} parent="Kids" />
              </SubCategories>
            </div>
          </Menu>

          <Menu as="div">
            <div
              className={`border-b-2 border-b-white hover:border-b-red-400 p-2`}
            >
              <p>About</p>
            </div>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

Comment: The [React Conditional Rendering docs page](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) shows a number of options for this, including a [simple `if...else` surrounding `return`ed JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#element-variables), [inline `if` with the logical `&&` operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator), and [inline ternary](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator).

Comment: yes I followed your steps and I update my code I cannot load icons now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

For the sake of your changes. You can use my function along with this. It will return an icon component for you.

```
return(
    { 
      id: data.id, 
      name: data.name, 
      icon: loadIcon(data),
      childs: data.childs
    }
  )
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You can try this way

```
function loadIcon(data) {
   const icons = {
      ['1']: <Icons2.frock01 />,
      ['2']: <Icons2.frock02 />,
      ['3']: <Icons2.frock03 />,
      ['4']: <Icons2.frock04 />,
   }
   return icons[data.id]
}
```

Usage

```
<>{loadIcon(data)}</>
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working

Comment: You can try my implementation here 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-uouuc5. Ps: I added dummy data for it to render `Testing` elements (in your case, should be icons)

Comment: By the way, I updated my answer too for the sake of your implementation.

Comment: Nick, can you help me with this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861163/react-useeffect-how-to-retrive-selected-array-data-and-view-that-data-and-its

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is put your `item.icon div` in conditional render like below.
And use `ternary operator`

```
{data.id === '1' ? 
  (
    <div className="col-span-1">{data.icon}</div>
  ) 
  : 
  (
    // Anything else you want to render
  )   
}
```

Comment: is this only for two statements? (If else) I need for more conditions

Comment: do you want to render your icons dynamically or statically?

Comment: Sir I need to render items according to the data.id value, as an example 
if (data.id = 1) {
<Icons2.frock01 />
} like wise for six icons then I want to call that return icon to replace this       icon: <Icons2.frock01 />,

Comment: ok, then you can map through if else.

Comment: can you give me an example my if-else is not woking

Comment: Sorry but it's hard for me to understand what you want clearly.

Comment: I have edited my code with if-else statement

Comment: ok got it. Well if you want to render `same icons` for some `id` then you're doing it correctly just wrap your last  `icon` in `{}`.

Comment: can you go through the code again I have a problem with calling the icon after rendering in if else

Comment: check the load icon function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242795/discussion-between-nuwan-chamikara-and-dharmik-patel).