# React UseEffect - How to retrive selected array data and view that data and its child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

***According to the selected chat I want to change the seller name.***

***this is the UI***

[image]

**This is my JSON data File**

```
{
    "person": [

      {
        "id": "userId",
        "sellerImage": "https://i.pravatar.cc/300",
        "lastOnline": "Date of last online",
        "sellerName": "Ryann Remo",
        "isOnline": true,
        "lastSeenDate": "Today",
        "product":"Rough Shirt",
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfUser",
            "message": "Message text 01",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text 02",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": true
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message 03",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "id": "userId",
        "sellerImage": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50",
        "lastOnline": "Date of last online",
        "sellerName": "Karp Bonolo",
        "isOnline": true,
        "lastSeenDate": "Yesterday",
        "product":"Rough Shirt",
        "messages": [
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfUser",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": true
          },
          {
            "id": "messageId",
            "userId": "userIdOfSeller",
            "message": "Message text",
            "date": "Date of message",
            "time": "time of message",
            "isRead": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**This is how I'm imported that JSON data**

```
import AdminConversationData from "./AdminConversation.json";

const AdminConversation = () => {




  const person = AdminConversationData.person.map((data) => {
    return {
      ...data,
    };
  });

.....
```

**This is how I'm going to select a person in react file**

```
<RadioGroup>
  <div className="space-y-2">
    {person.map((item, idx) => (
      <RadioGroup.Option
        key={item.id}
        value={item.id}
        onClick={() => setSelectPerson(idx)}
        className={({ active }) =>
          `${
            active
              ? 'ring-2 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-red-300 ring-white ring-opacity-60 border-l-4 border-red-500'
              : ''
          }
            relative rounded-lg shadow-md px-5 py-4 cursor-pointer flex focus:outline-none entry cursor-pointer 
            transform hover:scale-105 duration-300`
        }
        
      >
       
          <>
        <div className="flex-2">
          <div className="w-12 h-12 relative">
            <img
              className="w-12 h-12 rounded-full mx-auto"
              src={"https://picsum.photos/200"}
              alt="chat-user"
            />
            <span className="absolute w-4 h-4 bg-gray-400 rounded-full right-0 bottom-0 border-2 border-white"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2">
          <div className="truncate w-32">
            <span className="text-gray-800">{item.sellerName}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-600">Yea, Sure!</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-2 text-right">
          <div>
            <small className="text-gray-500">{item.lastSeenDate}</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <small className="text-xs bg-red-500 text-white rounded-full h-6 w-6 leading-6 text-center inline-block">
              23
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
          </>
      
      </RadioGroup.Option>
    ))}
  </div>
</RadioGroup>
```

***(this is React headless UI radio group and I'm going to select a certain person here.)***

**In this place, I want to retrieve that person's data as an example the seller's name.**

```
<>
 <div class="relative">
    <span class="absolute text-green-500 right-0 bottom-0">
       <svg width="20" height="20">
          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="currentColor" class="absolute right-0 w-4 h-4 bg-green-600 border-2 border-green-700 rounded-full top-2 animate-pulse"></circle>
       </svg>
    </span>
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="" class="w-10 sm:w-16 h-10 sm:h-16 rounded-full"/>
 </div>
 <div class="flex flex-col leading-tight">
    <div class="text-2xl mt-1 flex items-center">
      <span class="text-gray-700 mr-3">Seller Name</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span>
</div>
</>
```

***(In here at the seller name place I want to show the selected seller name.) And also If you can please help me to load the messeges according to slected person date and time this is additional one If you can please help me. below code related how I'm goning to show messeges.***

```
<>
      <div class="chat-message">
         <div class="flex items-end">
            <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2 text-xs max-w-xs mx-2 order-2 items-start">
               <div><span class="px-4 py-2 rounded-lg inline-block rounded-bl-none bg-gray-300 text-gray-600">Thanks for your message David. I thought I'm alone with this issue. Please,  the issue to support it :)</span></div>
            </div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="My profile" class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full order-1"/>
         </div>
      </div>
</>
```

Comment: Your code does not have enough info. Which component do you keep `Seller Name`? Is it under the same component as `RadioGroup`? How do you structure the relation between `setSelectedPerson` and the code of `Seller Name`?

Comment: Sir, please refer to the UI this is the same page, First I'm trying to select one person's chat, and according to that person's chat, I'm trying to load his chat box. `RadioGroup` for left-side chat selection. please check the last section that is where `RadioGroup`'s selected data going to load. the seller's name should be the selected person's name.

Comment: I know what you mean, but could you tell me `Seller Name` and `RadioGroup` are under the same component or different components?

Comment: same component sir !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state declaration can be like below

```
const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson] = useState()
```

*Note that I modified your function name from `setSelectPerson` to `setSelectedPerson` because `select` is a verb and not good to name a variable*

And then modify your `onClick` on `RadioGroup.Option`

```
onClick={() => setSelectedPerson(item)} //`item` actually is `person` object
```

After that, you can integrate your `selectedPerson` state into the main chat

```
<>
 <div class="relative">
    <span class="absolute text-green-500 right-0 bottom-0">
       <svg width="20" height="20">
          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="currentColor" class="absolute right-0 w-4 h-4 bg-green-600 border-2 border-green-700 rounded-full top-2 animate-pulse"></circle>
       </svg>
    </span>
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="" class="w-10 sm:w-16 h-10 sm:h-16 rounded-full"/>
 </div>
 <div class="flex flex-col leading-tight">
    <div class="text-2xl mt-1 flex items-center">
      <span class="text-gray-700 mr-3">{selectedPerson && selectedPerson.sellerName}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text-lg text-gray-600">Seller</span>
</div>
</>
```

For all chat messages, you also can use `selectedPerson`

```
selectedPerson && selectedPerson.messages && selectedPerson.messages.map((messageData) => <div key={messageData.id} class="chat-message">
         <div class="flex items-end">
            <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2 text-xs max-w-xs mx-2 order-2 items-start">
               <div><span class="px-4 py-2 rounded-lg inline-block rounded-bl-none bg-gray-300 text-gray-600">{messageData.message}</div>
            </div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549078642-b2ba4bda0cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=3&amp;w=144&amp;h=144" alt="My profile" class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full order-1"/>
         </div>
      </div>)
```

Comment: then there will be a error `selectedPerson` like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sellerName')`

Comment: Add this validation `selectedPerson && selectedPerson.sellerName`, it will help you to verify `selectedPerson` is existing or not. By the way, I added to the answer too @NuwanChamikara

Comment: I have added the code to this : https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-paper-u2kp0d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Nothing there, could you share a fully functional code? @NuwanChamikara

Comment: please refresh the link I have saved the code now. sorry for the messy code.

Comment: something is wrong with your sandbox, whenever I click on any items, it shows some random errors (not from the code). If you still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sellerName')`, you can add this `selectedPerson && selectedPerson.sellerName`

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `userId`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.`

Comment: The page is working but the name is not showing. The above error is there. In the code sandbox link, I have given the full code and JSON data. UI may not be working if you can please help me.

Comment: for the seller name showing place cant we add arrow function like this ? `{selectedPerson.map((data) => ( ...code... ))}`

Comment: `selectedPerson` is an object, you cannot do it, but you can add key to `messageData.id` like this `key={messageData.id}` under messages `map`